# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element : what should i do

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am web crwaling but I keep getting troubles...

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

there is a error in

```
    click = '//*[@id="pagerTagAnchor' + str(j) + '"]'
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(click).click()
```

what should i do?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

f = open('movie.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
options.add_argument("disable-gpu")

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)

for i in range(1, 101):
for j in range(1, 11):
    driver.get('https://movie.naver.com/movie/bi/mi/point.nhn?code=167638')
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    click = '//*[@id="pagerTagAnchor' + str(j) + '"]'
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(click).click()
    response = requests.get(str(driver.current_url))
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    notices1 = soup.select(
        'body > div > div > div.score_result > ul > li:nth-of-type(' + str(j) + ') > div.score_reple > p')

    for n in notices1:
        a = n.text.strip()
        a = str(a).replace(",", "")
    f.write(str(a) + ',')

f.close()
```

this is the full chord.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest that you are missing an "S" from your title.

Comment: @MadPhysicist thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to wait for locate the element. Here is function that find element by xpath

```
import logging
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

def findByXpath(locator, timeout = None):
    ''' Get one item by xpath'''
    if not timeout:
        timeout = 10
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, locator))
        )
        return element
    except TimeoutException:
        logging.info(' Find by xpath not found : %s', locator)
        logging.debug('%s', TimeoutException)
        return None
```